# MS Access Query-By-Form Issue

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I have a form (fCen1-20) containing two combo boxes. The first combo box is called Lookup Value and the dropdown contains the field Lookup_Value which serves as the primary key for every table in the database. The second combo box is called Category and the dropdown contains the fields Category, Code, and Table.

I would like for the user to select the Lookup Value and Category and for those selections to inform a query which returns the value of the selected Category for the selected Lookup Value. The complicating factor is that each Lookup Value is associated with over 1500 unique categories of information which are each assigned a unique code -- the code serves as the field name.

For your reference, I have pasted my code, along with my rationale, below:

```
SELECT [Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1].Code 
' Rationale: Get the value for the Code associated with a given category

FROM [Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1].Table 
' Rationale: Reference the Table where the selected Category/Code is housed

ON [Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1].Table.Lookup_Value = _ 
        [Forms]![fCen1-20].[Lookup Value]; 
' Rationale: Select only those records in the table 
' for which the Lookup_Value field matches the Lookup Value  
' selected in the form
```

When I run this code, I'm given a "Syntax error in FROM clause" error. Any suggestions on how to make this work? Please let me know if you'd like any additional detail or clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use this in a query, it will probably work assuming the form *fCen1-20* is open in Form View.

```sql
SELECT [Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1]
```

The value returned will be from the bound column of the currently selected combo box row.  The fact that `[Category 1]` includes 3 columns does not matter.  The db engine only sees the column which is "bound".  (Check the combo's Bound Column property on the Data tab of the combo's property sheet.)  The bound value is the only combo value available in a query.

You can not append a column name to the combo name to retrieve the values from those columns, so these will both fail:

```sql
[Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1].Code
[Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1].Table
```

That was my explanation for why I believe your approach is not working.  However, I don't know what to suggest instead.  In general, if you use a table's primary key as a combo's bound value, you can use that bound value with a `DLookup` expression in a query.  As an example, assuming all values are numeric ...

```sql
SELECT fld1, fld2, etc
FROM YourTable
WHERE some_field = DLookup(
    "lookup_field",
    "AnotherTable",
    "pkey_field = " & [Forms]![fCen1-20]![Category 1]
    );
```

Unfortunately I don't know whether that suggestion is useful for your situation because I don't clearly understand what you're trying to accomplish.